# Spring annotation for HTTP method

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there any spring annotation available for capturing http method.
essentially I have a legacy controller where a single method is handling POST, PUT, PATCH.

Now I need to add a funcitonality which is applicable only for POST. Thus i want to throw an error if consumer sends request with method other than POST. 
Thus I want to capture the request method.

I know I can get it easily using httpservletrequest.getMethod() but I want to use spring's annotation to capture it. This will be help me keep my code clean.

Query: Does spring support any annotation through which I can capture http the request  method.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
@GetMapping
@PostMapping
@PutMapping
(...)
```

and others

When you put for example @GetMapping and try to request another method you will automatically receive HTTP error 405 - method not allowed.

Available since version 4.3.

Comment: I think my question was not clear. i do not want to validate it. In my case, there is a single method which handles POST, PUT & PATCH. I need to do some processing when method is POST. Thus wanted to know if I can capture the incoming method type using any spring annotation.